# mysql and php login page with mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, mysql-num-rows

I have those codes and its give me an error 'Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource' :

PHP:

```
<?php
@error_reporting(0);
@session_start();
@include("sql.php");
$log_error = "";

if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
$user = protect($_POST['username']);
$pass = protect($_POST['password']);
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE name = '".$user."' and pass = '".$pass."'",$sqlc);
$count = mysql_num_rows($q);

if($count > 0) {
    $_SESSION['username'] == $user;
    header('Location: index.php');
    $log_error = "0";
} else {
    $log_error = "1";
}
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<table border="0">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="width:100%;"><span>Login</span></td>
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="width:100%;"><input type="submit" name="send" value="Login" /></td>
            </tr>
            </form>
        </table>
```

And the SQL connection (sql.php):

```
<?php
$Host = 'localhost';
$User = 'dash_sys1';
$Pass = '123456Ben';
$DB = 'dash_sys1';

$sqlc = mysql_connect($Host,$User,$Pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($DB) or die(mysql_error());
function protect($str) {
return htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($str)));
}
?>
```

its gives me that error:  Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\cms\admin\login.php on line 11

what I did wrong?

Comment: It means that mysql_query failed. Check the query and try adding an `or die()` to the end of it. You should also move away from the deprecated mysql_* functions and switch to PDO or mysqli, as the mysql_* functions will be removed in the next version of PHP.

Comment: the connection code seems to be correct. Must be ur mysql connection settings are not correct. Anyways, I noticed one bug in setting session variable in line `$_SESSION['username'] == $user;`. Should have been `$_SESSION['username'] = $user;`.

Comment: @Rajesh - it's not an issue with the connection to the database; it's because mysql_query returned a boolean, which generally means that there's an error in the SQL. But the OP isn't checking the return value, or looking to see if there's anything in `mysql_error()`

Comment: you see that 2nd param `$sqlc` to `mysql_query()`? If the connection was not created successfully, then php will try to connect using that connection object, which will fail the query.

Comment: Qhy are you HTMLSpecialChars'ing your fields?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

This means that you passed a non-resource to the function. So why would $q be a non-resource? The mysql_query() function returns a boolean **false** value if you have an error in your SQL query or usage of the function.  So $q is assigned the false value, not a query result resource.  Then you pass $q to mysql_num_rows() and that's not going to work.

You should always check the return value of mysql_query() for the **false** result.

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE name = '".$user."' and pass = '".$pass."'",$sqlc);
if ($q === false) {
    trigger_error(mysql_error($sqlc), E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
    $count = mysql_num_rows($q);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only things that I can suggest are the following, switch to MySqli, it is much easier to work with than regular mysql.

Also, it appears your query is reversed what it should be, try doing the following:

```
$q = mysql_query($sqlc, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE name = '".$user."' and pass = '".$pass."'");
```

Try that, if it does not work, let me know!

Comment: PDO is even better than `mysqli` because it has named placeholders like `:user` in addition to the the more generic `?`.

Comment: mysql_query() expects the first argument to be the SQL string, the second optional argument is the connection resource.

Comment: Really? I am going to have to research more into PDO, and also I am going to have a refresher in plain MySQL, apparently it has been a while and I have forgotten! My bad!